# How to clone the order grid

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to make a copy of the order grid. What I did:

I created view/adminhtml/layout/ecommerce_grid_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="ecommerce_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

created file: view/adminhtml/ui_component/ecommerce_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <spinner>sales_order_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="sales_order_grid_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Strix_EcommerceGrid::ecommerce</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="sales_order_grid_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>main_table.entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <options class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options"/>
                    <caption translate="true">All Store Views</caption>
                    <label translate="true">Purchase Point</label>
                    <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">ns = ${ $.ns }, componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <settings>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid.sales_order_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="increment_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="store_id" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Purchase Point</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Purchase Date</label>
                <sorting>desc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="grand_total" class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PurchasedPrice">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Grand Total (Purchased)</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="status" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <options class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status\Options"/>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

But unfortunately, the grid is loading all the time:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try with developer mode or please check browser console.

Comment: console has no errors

Comment: data from mui/index/render is returning correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, if you want to clone the grid, you are required to have suffix from data source to be the same as the ui_component file name. Ex: **sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid_data_source** must be changed to **ecommerce_grid.sales_order_grid_data_source**.